# How to Decode ASN.1 format to CSV format using Unix Programing

Tags: unix

I have ASN format files i have to convert into CSV format also readable one

I need a Decoder with some advanced options like schedule,Auto FTP like that

Comment: Do you have the corresponding ASN.1 syntax file? Which encoding do the files use; BER, DER, PER, ...?

Comment: What do you mean by "Unix programming"? Do you have a preference for a particular programming language?

Comment: Not needed in Java.Any Decoder is fine

Comment: I'm a little confused. Why are you saying it doesn't have to be Java when I never mentioned Java? I only ask because I might be misinterpreting your comment.

Comment: I have ASN format files.i have to convert into CSV format should be readable one

I need a Decoder with some advanced options like autorun

Answer (score 1):

Pretty old thread but it still comes at top on Google search and it will be good for people to get an answer. Not exactly Unix programming but you can find a "generic" Javascript based ASN decoder at http://lapo.it/asn1js/.

You can also download this and run natively on your box.

Answer (score 0):

Erlang provides very good support for reading and writing BER-, DER- and PER-encoded ASN.1 packets. The Erlang compiler even accepts ASN.1 syntax natively and produces a custom codec as an Erlang module.

It's a whole new programming language for most people though, so whether it's worth learning it just for this exercise, I'll leave up to you. It is a very fun language to learn, however, and will teach you a very different way to think about programming.

Comment: @Anand: There's no such thing. ASN.1 allows for the specification of very rich and complex data formats. There is simply no way for a generic tool to know how to convert any arbitrary ASN.1 into comma-separated text.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [asn1 compiler](http://lionet.info/asn1c/). 
It converts asn.1 syntax files to C code.
As Marcelo noted in you question, you didn't exactly say precisely what you need, so can't tell if it covers all your bases, but you will be able to compile the code to binary (from C code, obviously)

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source package called asn1c which will do ASN.1 encoding and decoding. Its a C library that you need to build and then write code around to implement your program. In order to build the library, it requires the ASN.1 syntax file that is used to construct the encoded messages. When decoding, one option is to output the data to an XML file which you would then need to convert to a CSV file somehow. At a minimum, it supports BER, XER, and PER.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, there is also the PyASN1 library and tools: http://pyasn1.sourceforge.net/